# Db not connecting -php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch table `categories` data from DB named `stores`. Here when I run this code it displays the DB error mentioned ie. `Could not select the indicated database`. How to resolve it? My DB name is correct plus `$con` variable is also not accessed in `index.php` while calling the function. Why is it so?
Note: The class code was in `MySQL` which is now depreciated. I have tried to convert it into `MySQL`.

**index.php**

```
require_once("ajax_table.class.php");
$obj = new ajax_table();
$records = $obj->getRecords($conn);
```

**config.php**

```
define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define ( 'DB_DB', 'stores' );
```

**ajax_table.class.php**

```
 class ajax_table {
    private $conn;
  public function __construct(){

    $this->$conn=$this->dbconnect();
  }

  private function dbconnect() {
     $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DB)
      or die ("<div style='color:red;'><h3>Could not connect to MySQL server</h3></div>");
      return $conn;
  }

  function getRecords($conn){
    $this->res = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from categories");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($this->res)){
        while($this->row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->res)){
            $record = array_map('stripslashes', $this->row);
            $this->records[] = $record; 
        }
        return $this->records;
    }
    //else echo "No records found";
  }
```

Comment: I can't see where you are using config.php. You have to set your database name ...

Comment: You don't need to call `mysqli_select_db()` because you're already selecting the database in the `mysqli_connect()` call. It's possible `mysqli_select_db()` returns false because it didn't actually need to switch databases.

Comment: Also, your ajax_table class is missing an ending brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the parameters to `mysqli_select_db` switched. Check out [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) which has the syntax and also suggests using the 4th parameter to `mysqli_connect` to select the database instead. As Rishi's answer noted, you're actually already doing that, so you can remove this call entirely!

Regarding the `$conn` variable, you are returning `$conn` from dbconnect, but not doing anything with it. You probably want to have a property on the class:

```
private $conn;
```

Then in `dbconnect` do something like:

```
$this->conn = $this->dbconnect();
```

And use `$this->conn` in `getRecords` instead of a parameter.

There are several ways you can solve this; the fundamental point is that you need the return from `dbconnect` to be kept somewhere and made available when you need to talk to the DB.

Comment: It worked Sir! But what about accessing `$conn` within index.php file?

Comment: [Moved to the answer]

Comment: You need `$this->conn` rather than `$this->$conn`. You're still passing `$conn` to `getRecords` too: Don't need that, just use `$this->conn` there as well.

Comment: Oh! perfect :) Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

I cant see that you have included your config page into your database class?

Add this to your database class:

```
<?php require_once("config.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Yes i have included it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `mysqli_select_db` as you already selecting database in `mysqli_connect`.

Remove below line from your code

```
mysqli_select_db(DB_DB,$conn)
  or die ("<div style='color:red;'><h3>Could not select the indicated database</h3></div>");
```

Comment: removed! ad it worked. But what about `$conn` to be accessed in `index.php`

Comment: Either you can return `$conn` or better use in class at setter in constructor  and get where you need and there will no need to pass any param like in getRecords method.

Comment: as dbconnect method is private set it in constructor would be better, otherwise you need to make it public method.

Comment: as you updated your code. change here also. replace `function getRecords($conn){` to `function getRecords(){ $conn =  $this->conn` and also remove `$conn` param from `$records = $obj->getRecords($conn);`